# Term for using your own words against you

Tags: terminology, literary-device

Could anyone tell me the literary term (if one exists) for using someone's own words against them in the future. For example, in The Merchant of Venice when Shylock states he wants to 'catch Antonio once upon the hip' and later Gratiano repeats this to Shylock as an insult.

Comment: Dramatic irony.

Comment: It's "media bias", obviously!

Comment: Avoid posting questions that do not detail the effort you have already made to find an answer, solutions you have already rejected, and why. Such questions may be closed as lacking research effort until they are edited to include research. Research can take many forms: checking references such as an online English dictionary, thesaurus, or grammar, searching this site for similar questions, searching the web, or putting substantial thought into the question on your own. See: “[How much research is needed? – EL&U Meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5039#5043)”.

Comment: @MetaEd I'm not sure _I_'d know where to start when it comes to researching this one (perhaps looking for synonyms of 'tit for tat', 'taste of his own medicine' – but this assumes one is cognisant with these expressions). //  A duplicate has just been posted.

Answer (score 7):

How about the Shakespearean *[hoist(ed) by one's own petard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoist_with_his_own_petard)*?

Comment: Avoid posting answers that lack explanation, context, and supporting facts. A good expert answer includes this information to demonstrate that it is correct. This is what makes the answer useful – not only to the asker, but to future visitors to the page.

Expert partial answers are welcome, but notions, trial balloons, offhand ideas, guesses, anecdotes, and general discussion are not answers.

If you are unsure what the asker is looking for, a better way is to request clarification in a comment on the question.